# android.sources in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-ndk

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"

import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os


model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = "com.XXX.YYY"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
        }

        ndk{
            moduleName "decode"
        }


        sources{
            main.jni {
                source {
                    srcDirs = ['src/main/none'] // [] could be set instead but will disable even symbol resolution inside the editor
                    //srcDirs = []
                }
            }
            main.jniLibs {
                source {
                    srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
                }
            }
        }

/*

        sourceSets.main {
            jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            // This is not necessary unless you have precompiled libraries in your project.
        }
*/



        task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
            //def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory             //will not work. property name change. name is not stabilized
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
            def ndkDir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')

            commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                    '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
                    '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
                    'all',
                    'NDK_DEBUG=1'
        }

        task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
            //def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory             //will not work. property name change. name is not stabilized
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
            def ndkDir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')

            commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                    '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
                    'clean'
        }

        clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
        }


        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-android.txt"))
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
            }
        }

    }

}
    dependencies {
        compile files('libs/real3d.jar')
    }
```

This is my build.gradle file. I have done a lot of efforts to avoid auto generation of Android.mk file. 
problem is in  android.sources

It gives the error:

> Error:Attempt to read a write only view of model of type
>   'org.gradle.model.ModelMap'
>   given to rule 'android { ... } @ app/build.gradle line 7, column 5'

Any help will be aprreciated.

Comment: @NIPHIN  I was using  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental  for reference

Comment: so you dont know gradle?

Comment: @NIPHIN not in very depth.. Am I missing something?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by model {} , remove it it should work fine if you haven't add it intentionally

Comment: have you added classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4" in root build.gradle ?

Comment: @NIPHIN i have done all that.